# Best data combination to ensure web user uniqueness?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to ensure that the anonymous web users that voting using your poll-system are unique (*each anonymous user votes for once only*)?

**I can think of:**
 1. Client's IP Address
 2. Client's Machine Name
 3. MAC Address
 4. Storing cookie

As far as I know, you cant get (2) & (3) in web development, and (4) is not guaranteed since user can delete/not allow cookies

what do you think is better to achieve uniqueness?

Comment: MAC address will not be available since they are only known to the layer two router. There seems to be an activeX solution that only works in IE with changed security settings. Not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The only safe way to achieve uniqueness is to have users to log in.

Using only IP is not good enough as IP can be messed with and there may be several users behind the same IP

Even MAC address can be easily changed (there are freeware tools for it)

Cookies are obviously not very reliable

Comment: well, you still need to prevent users from creating multiple accounts somehow ...

Answer (score 0):

I think only a log in system with external (non IT, human system) based authentication would give a very high level of certainty e.g. to support voting for government but for lessor purposes consider browser uniqueness

[Web Browsers Leave 'Fingerprints' Behind as You Surf the Net](https://www.eff.org/press/archives/2010/05/13)
[Browser Fingerprinting Can ID You Without Cookies](http://www.pcworld.com/article/188161/browser_fingerprinting_can_id_you_without_cookies.html)

Answer (score 0):

To comment on you ideas:

1) IP adress may be shared between lot of users (for example my IP adress is same for whole block of flats...), which can be an issue

2,3) yes, probably not possible without some browser extensions or other stuff like that

4) cookies can be deleted, but some sort of third party cookies (via iframe for example) may be simple kind-of-solution, because user may not look for it in cookie list... If I want to vote on example.com, I probably would not look for cookie from example2.com... I hope I made  myself clear how I mean this.

And I would add browser agent string as number 5.

But other answers are correct that registration with mailing confirmation code through post or something is likely only "safe" solution. But your question was for anonymous so...

Definitely it is NOT possible to be 100% sure that user is unique...